# Android get container width instead of display width

Tags: java, android

I want to display a text of variable length in a `cardView`. To make the text fit, I split the text after every 500 Chars and add the substring to another `relativeLayout` which is then added to a `HorizontalScrollView`. 
But I must define a length of the  `relativeLayout`, otherwise it is just a long one-liner in the ScrollView. Currently I do it with `display.getWidth()` and then shrink it to 0.8.

*The code works fine like this.* But 
firstly this method is depreciated and secondly is it a bit static I think. 
What are better solutions?

The creation of the fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View layoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_story,
                    container, false);

    LinearLayout storyText = layoutView.findViewById(R.id.story_text_linear_layout);


    //Here I get The width of the display:
    android.view.Display display = ((android.view.WindowManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            (int)(display.getWidth()*0.8),
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );

    params.setMargins(0, 0, 10, 0);


    String text = story.getStory();
    while(text.length()>500){

        TextView t = new TextView(storyText.getContext());
        t.setText(text.substring(0,500));
        text =text.substring(500);

        RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(storyText.getContext());
        rl.setLayoutParams(params);
        rl.addView(t);
        storyText.addView(rl);

    }
    TextView t = new TextView(storyText.getContext());
    t.setText(text);

    RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(storyText.getContext());
    rl.setLayoutParams(params);

    rl.addView(t);
    storyText.addView(rl);


    TextView author = layoutView.findViewById(R.id.author_text);
    author.setText(story.getAuthor());


    return layoutView;
}
```

and the xml if someone needs that to have a better understanding:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="xyz.myrating.stories.mystories.RecyclerList.StoryFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout_root_storyfrag"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:cropToPadding="false"
                android:src="@drawable/spacer" />

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/story_text_linear_layout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" />
            </HorizontalScrollView>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/author_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:text="Huckleberry Finn"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/spacer" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numStars="1"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:rating="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What exactly is the outcome you're trying to achieve ? What kind of scrolling you want ? If you have a long text and fix size card layout then it would be scroll

Comment: I want to display a text of variable length in a cardView. Scroll: HorizontalScrollView (Nothing more, Nothing less). Have you read the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obtaining display width is wrong for this purpose because your application is not guaranteed to be ran fullscreen.

Any `android.view.View` has `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` methods which return the actual width and height in the container. They will return `0` until the layout process finished, so you should obtain the values after layout has been finished. This is achieved as follows

```
storyFrag.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
    new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            storyFrag.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
            handleYourDimensions(storyFrag.getWidth())
        }
    }
)
```

However, there is something conceptually wrong with what you are trying to achieve. You should not split your text manually, instead, set the required width of your `TextView` so it cuts the text for you automatically.

Also, why do you need a `HorizontalScrollView` for your text? Do you want the actual text container to be wider than a screen and be scrollable horizontally? This seems pretty inconvenient.